# How to assign variable to value attribute in input element?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to assign variable to `value` attribute in the `input` element

Here is my input tag.

```
<input type="text" id="Name" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Usernam" value="myValue">
```

Here is my variable.

```
var myValue = document.getElementById('userVal');
```

Anyone, please help me to fix this problem?

Comment: var myValue = document.getElementById("Name").value;

Answer (score 3):

You can set input default value. You can not bind myValue in the html without some js framework. To get input value use change event. Check my code snippet.

```js
var input = document.getElementById('Name');
var myValue = 'Name example';
input.value = myValue;

var myFunction = function (e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Name" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Usernam" onchange="myFunction(event)" value="myValue">
```

Answer (score 0):

### ASSIGN INPUT VALUE TO VARIABLE:

You need to assign the variable to the element's value, not the element itself. Also, your current input id is `Name`, not `userVal`. Change that to `userVal` then retrieve the value like this:

```
var myValue = document.getElementById('userVal').value;
```

---

Check the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example on how to retrieve an input value and assign it to a variable:

```js
/* JavaScript */

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
var myValue = document.getElementById('userVal').value;
alert(myValue);
})
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<input type="text" id="userVal" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Username">
<button>Check Value</button>
```

### ASSIGN VARIABLE TO INPUT VALUE:

To assign your input element's value to a variable, just reverse the above assignment like this:

```
var newValue = newValue;
document.getElementById('userVal').value = newValue;
```

Check the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example on how to assign a variable to your input element's value attribute:

```js
/* JavaScript */

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var newValue = "newValue"; 
  document.getElementById('userVal').value = newValue;
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<input type="text" id="userVal" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Original" value="myValue">
<br /><br />
<button>Change Value</button>
```

Comment: But my friend i canot use `var myValue = document.getElementById('userVal').value;` instead of `var myValue = document.getElementById('userVal')` Because this `myValue` defied by below firebase query. `dbRefName.on('value', snap => myValue.innerText = snap.val()); `

Comment: So you are trying to pull data from your firebase and push it as a value to your input or?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I am trying to pull data from firebase database and try to put this value to input tag's value like some kind of this `value="userVal"` attribute.

Comment: But why can't you use `var myValue = document.getElementById('userVal').value` after firebase has set it's value first though?

Comment: I've already tried it, bro. the chrome console said `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of undefined`

Comment: Do you have a live link of your site? I can check it out.

Comment: Still not live., But you can see my full script from below link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rGE3-esBhDZ1olDgbeQ4DYEQS7bFIArI/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

if you want to assign value to this input:

```
<input type="text" id="Name" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Usernam" value="myValue">
```

you should use this code:

```
var myValue = document.getElementById('userVal').value;
document.getElementById("Name").value = myValue;
```

You can look to the documentation and example here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

Comment: But my friend i canot use `var myValue = document.getElementById('userVal').value`; instead of `var myValue = document.getElementById('userVal')` Because this myValue defined by below firebase query. `dbRefName.on('value', snap => myValue.innerText = snap.val());`

Comment: Than, i don't understand your question, you asked:

"How to assign variable to value attribute in input element?" 

You can assign variable "any_variable" to input with id "any_input_id" with code:


document.getElementById("any_input_id").value =  any_variable;

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, add value property to your code as:

```
    var myValue = document.getElementById("name").value
```

In HTML, use the same id to refer the input tag as:

```
    <input type="text" id="Name" class="form-control form-control-alternative" placeholder="Usernam" value="myValue">
```